# Lotus notes DXL attachments

Tags: lotus-notes

I tried using an online base 64 decoder and managed to decode text and picture attachments successfully.

However, when it comes to MS word and Excel attachments, i was unable to decode it
Could you please suggest me the correct decoding method.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Post the MIME headers for the message that you are trying to process so we can look at them.

Comment: the sample encoded string is here http://www.page-monitor.com/Downloads/test.txt. i want to decode the above content and write it to a docx file

Comment: It appears to be valid base64 data.  What are you using to try to decode it?

Comment: System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
                    System.Text.Decoder utf8Decode = encoder.GetDecoder();

                    byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
                    int charCount = utf8Decode.GetCharCount(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length);
                    char[] decoded_char = new char[charCount];

                    utf8Decode.GetChars(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length, decoded_char, 0);

                    result = new String(decoded_char);

Comment: I could get all types of attachments extraction done by using base64 decoding and getting array of bytes and writing to the file in binary mode.

Comment: If the word and excel files are binary, then I think you probably don't want to be going through the utf8Decode step.

Comment: I was able to decode that file using http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/. The document opened fine - single pager with lots of bullet points.

Answer (score 0):

If a base64-decoding still results "garbage content" - there is a probability the data also has been compressed (with Huffman or LZ1 method). Check "compression" attribute value of its enclosing  tag.

If the attribute indicates a compression - it is quite tricky to uncompress. A better idea would be to export the DXL again with setUncompressAttachments(true) mode of DXLExporter.

Comment: thanks for the reply after so many years, I will ask my team to work on it with these suggested changes in next build.